# IIS7 / FTP 7.5 - how to access outside FTP root directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, ftp

Is it possible to set access any directories outside the FTP root with Windows Server 2008 and FTP 7.5 server? I have FTP User Isolation set to 'User name directory' and have created a virtual directory under the LocalUser directory with the same name of the user which links to an external directory. But this isn't working so I guess it's not the right way to do it.
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions for you.  In IIS 7(.5), you can click on the FTP Directory Browsing icon and turn on Directory Listing Options: "Virtual Directories" which will display it for you.

The other option is to create a blank folder with the same name, where the vdir is.  Then it will show up in the listing, although if you navigate to it with FTP the vdir will 'catch' instead and direct you to where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding a virtual directory does work - it just doesn't show up in the FTP directory listing. You have to type in it's address manually to get to it.